# Verificar se o usuario está ativo no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Preciso fazer uma consulta se o usuario está ativo. Ex.

Eu cliente faço o login no painel, se meu status for de desativado, me mostra uma mensagem, se meu status for de ativo loga na página.

segue meu codigo

```
    <?php
    // inclui o arquivo de inicialização
    include_once('assets/conn/init.php');

    // resgata variáveis do formulário
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : '';
    // cria o hash da senha
    $passwordHash = make_hash($password);

    $PDO = db_connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email AND senha = :password";
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $passwordHash);
    $stmt->execute();

    $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    //Se o email não existir na base de dados gera um alerta
    if (count($users) <= 0):
        header('Location: index.php?msg=1');
        exit;
    endif;

    // pega o primeiro usuário
    $user = $users[0];
     session_start();
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['usuario_id'];
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $user['nome'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
    $_SESSION['nivel_usuario'] = $user['nivel_usuario'];
    header('Location: home.php');
```

Comment: Uma solução é inserir na sua tabela `usuários` um campo `status` onde por exemplo o valor 1 configuraria um usuário ativo e 0, inativo. Ao jogar todos os usuários da consulta no array `users`, você pode verificar o valor do campo `status`, dependendo disso, você mostra o alerta de inativo, caso esteja.

Comment: No banco de dados já tenho essa coluna que se chama "ativo", como faço essa aplicação no meu código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o usuário está ativo ou não usando o campo da tabela chamado `status`

Exemplo:

```
//Se o email não existir na base de dados gera um alerta
if (count($users) <= 0):
    header('Location: index.php?msg=1');
    exit;
endif;

$user = $users[0];
// 1 ativo
// 2 Inativo
if ($user['status'] == 1):
    // pode ser usado um redirect
    header('Location: index.php?msg=2'); 
    exit;
endif;
```

Comment: Não tinha visto a resposta do colega acima... mas que bom que estamos corretos!

Comment: Obg manow... deu certinho

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você já tem a coluna ativo criada e que os valores sejam booleanos 0 ou 1, faça assim:

```
//.............
//Se o email não existir na base de dados gera um alerta
if (count($users) <= 0):
    header('Location: index.php?msg=1');
    exit;
endif;

// pega o primeiro usuário
$user = $users[0];

if($user['ativo'] == 0){
    header('Location: index.php?msg=Esse usuário não está ativo');
    exit;
}
```